# setting custom permissions for the file and inheriting ownership from pattern folder in JS

Tags: node.js, file-permissions, shelljs

I need to set custom permission and inherit ownership from parent directory after writing to file in JS. I'm using to `shelljs` to run the commands.

I'm running the following to get the owner and group of the parent directory:

`` const ownerGroup = shelljs.exec('ls -la ../ | grep -e "`basename $(pwd)`$"  | awk \'{print $3, $4}\'').split(' '); ``

The commands to set the permissions and ownership are as follows:

```
const owner = ownerGroup[0];
const group = ownerGroup[1];
shelljs.exec(`sudo chown ${owner}:${group} ${process.env.CONFIG_FILE}`);
shelljs.exec(`sudo chmod 660 ${process.env.CONFIG_FILE}`);
```

The file path is in `process.env.CONFIG_FILE`. I run into issues with `chown` as is doesn't see the file path. The command is structured correctly, but the path shifts to the new line.

```
COMMAND ->  sudo chown yury.stanev:yury.stanev
/home/yury.stanev/menlolab/runner/config.json
chown: missing operand after ‘yury.stanev:yury.stanev’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by replacing any new line character in cmd with nothing.

`` const cmd = `sudo chown ${owner}:${group} ${process.env.CONFIG_FILE}`.replace('\n', ''); ``